# Trigger Autofill Service in login page of Chrome Browser

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo, android-autofill-manager

I can able to get the Autofill Service event in facebook app's login page for OREO and above OS versions.

```
@Override
public void onFillRequest(@NonNull FillRequest request, @NonNull CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, @NonNull FillCallback callback) {
}
```

But is this possible to get the Autofill Service event from facebook's login page in chrome browser or from some other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from Android P onwards AutofillService also working with chrome browser. Check [Compatibility mode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services)